# Displaying Most Recent Feeds from RSS Feed URL

Tags: angular

I am new in Angular 4, just want to ask for some help on how I can display details of the Top 3 most recent blogs (title, image,link). I was given an rss feed  url (XML).

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar for a blog usign **medium** RSS feed service, if you're trying to do that, keep in mind you have to filter feeds that have tags (feeds without tags are comments because in medium post and comments are feeds too).